# How to record SSIS reports in ruby & watir

Tags: ruby, ssis, watir

I am trying to automate web application which uses SSIS reports. I am able to navigate to all pages in the site and also see the all report pages.

When I click on Show Report button, report will display in Frame and then unable to go further actions.

Answer (score 0):

Watir works with frames: http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Frames